# Can I calculate Cohen's d (effect size) by hand if I have two means with their SD in a within subjects design?

Tags: mean, repeated-measures, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, cohens-d

I have several within-subjects studies that assess more or less the same intervention, but measure the outcome with different outcome measures. Most of my studies display the outcome in mean ± SD, compare these two means and give p-values. I wanted to calculate an effect size in Cohen's d per study by hand and i wanted to know whether that is statistically possible and correct. Also, i wanted to know which SD i have to choose in this case, if the formula is ((mean 1- mean 2)/SD).

Thanks!

Comment: What makes d a good thing to compute in this context?  And who do you know your distribution is such that SD is a good dispersion measure?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Personally, I want to calculate an effect size per study to compare interventions. In other words, i have 5 five studies that assess the effect of a certain intervention but only display the effect in mean ± sd; they have checked for normal distribution in their population. So i was wondering whether i can calculate an effect in the form of standardized mean difference/cohen's d

Comment: Treatments have effects on the absolute outcome measure.  Even for the same outcome measure, SDs can vary over studies making comparability of Cohen's d questionable.  Why should we judge an effect by how subjects disagree with one another on the effect?